# Evenly spacing multiple line item text without using a table

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to create an unordered list of `<a>text1 text2 text3</a>` elements, with a while loop.  This list is then styled using  `#sidebar li a` in my CSS.

My problem is that the text1, text2, text3 that is passed into each `<a>` element in my while loop can take on different lengths and I would like for them to be spaced equally like a table.  However, I CANNOT use a table, because to format like a table, requires me to do this....

```
<li><a><tr><td>text1</td> <td>text2</td> <td>text3</td></tr></a></li>...
```

and because of that, my CSS "background" image will repeat for EACH `<td>`, when I only want the background image ONCE for each `<tr>`...(using different style tags than shown below)

Is there a way to change my while loop to space my text1,text2,text3 evenly like a table (without using a table) and maintain my CSS background image ONCE per each `<li>`? Any help would be INCREDIBLY appreciated!

#### My PHP file

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{      

echo "<ul id=\"sidebar\">";
echo "<li><a href=\"#\">" . $row['column1'] . " ". $row['column2']. " ". $row['column 3']."</a></li></ul>";
}
```

#### My CSS file

```
#sidebar li a {
background: url(../images/sidebar.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: @Rees: it's hard to decipher your question. Perhaps you could edit to make it clearer.

Comment: You want all the rendered `$row['columns']` to be within one `<a>` within one `<li>` to be rendered with the same width? Without applying any additional formatting to the `$row['column1']`s? I'm not sure I understand your question, or even *why*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{      

echo "<ul id=\"sidebar\">;
echo "<li><a href=\"#\"><span class="psuedo-col">" . $row['column1'] . "</span> <span class="psuedo-col">". $row['column2']. "</span> <span class="psuedo-col">". $row['column 3']."</span></a></li></ul>";

}
```

Add `<span>`s around the content from the `$row['...']`, in order that the css has something to serve as a hook, and set an explicit width on those spans. Bearing in mind that if the content of the spans is too large it will either require an `overflow` rule (`hidden`, `visible` or `auto`) or your content will start to look odd.

As an example

```
span.psuedo-col {

display: inline-block;
width: 10em;
overflow: hidden;

}
```

Or you could use

```
`display: block;
/* other stuff */
float: left; /* or right, depending on your alignment requirements */
```

The floats, obviously, will take the contents of the spans out of the flow of the document, perhaps causing the `<li>` itself to collapse, sine it'll have no content.

Comment: oh my goodness. you're AWESOME, that worked perfectly!  Thanks soo much!

Answer (score 0):

Asfar as I understand your question, you want your `LI` elements to have a fixed width like `TD` in a table:

```
#sidebar li {
  float:left;
  width:33%; /* three columns with equal width */
}
```

Comment: No, it seems that he wants each of his rendered `$row['column1']` to have equal width, within *one* `<li>`. I don't know why, but that's what it looks like, as written currently... =/

Comment: actually EACH li, would equate to each TR, instead of TD..is there a solution for that?  sorry for the unformatted question.